# Running javafx application on java 1.8

Tags: java, javafx

I have noticed that in jdk folder javafx-src.zip is separate from src.zip.
Is it included in the jre? Will it run in all java 8 VMs?

Comment: First hit on Google ["java 8 javafx"](https://google.com/search?q=java+8+javafx): [Oracle Java FX Overview - Availability](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#A1095238)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have noticed that in jdk folder javafx-src.zip is separate from src.zip. Is it included in the jre?

No.  The JRE only needs to include binary runtime code, it does not need to include source code.  Only the JDK includes source code.  So, the JRE includes neither src.zip, nor javafx-src.zip.

> Will it run in all java 8 VMs?

VMs yes, JREs no.  For example if you have an Oracle server JRE or an OpenJDK JRE distribution which does not include JavaFX client runtime code, then your JavaFX application will not run on those environments.  All full (non-server only) distributions of Oracle Java SE 8 (except Solaris) include a compatible runtime for JavaFX 8, so you can execute a JavaFX 8 compatible application directly on the Oracle Java SE 8 JRE without any additional installations.

To ensure that your target machine has a compatible JRE installed for executing your application, you may wish to package your application as a [self-contained application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes as of JDK 7u6 JavaFX is included with the standard JDK and JRE bundles.
Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html